# How to export results into a table continuously?

Tags: r

I've exported a dataset from Jan to Dec to a working directory and wanted to follow such one table by other new data with the same heading.

I've tried to export the dataset one by one and then combined all of them together into a single file.

```
a1 = getdata(Jan,Feb) ## data from Jan to Feb

write.table(a1,file="D:/q1.csv",sep=",")

a2 = getdata(Mar,Apr) ## data from Mar to Apr

write.table(a2,file="D:/q1.csv",sep=",")

# then I combined all the data in the excel.
```

My trial is inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you combine all the data in `R` and then export only one file ?

Comment: Are you looking for `write.table(a2, file = "D:/q1.csv", append = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think @jogo and julien's answers are helpful to me. If I can't get the data from Jan to Dec at one time and need to call the data set online quarter by quarter, how should I do?  The data set is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your data in R before you export it

```
a <- rbind(a1,a2)
write.table(a,file="",sep=",")
```